Is Suicide really sin?
My adults told me suicide is sin and person will wanders till his time comes. Lakh of people suicide every year. Do all of them wanders

Yes rules are same for everyone all of them suffer

See being born as human is rare out of 84 lakh yoni only one is human. that with proper pysic, is rare, with hand, leg and eyes ...several people are not having this luxury, one use body for helping those in need physically as well instead wasting

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2959/what-does-hinduism-say-about-suicide it is a similar question
